# Log4j2 filter for thread name

Tags: java, filter, log4j2

We have a log4j2 pattern layout which looks like following:

```
<PatternLayout>
   <pattern>%d{ISO8601} %5p - [%t] - %m%n</pattern>
</PatternLayout>
```

The thread-name is printed out every line. We now have the requirement to filter the log by the thread-names. We have tried the regex-filter but it seems to work only for the message part (%m) of the line.

Is there a way to directly filter on the thread-name with another provided filter or getting the thread-name into the message part, without editing all logging statements? Then we could use the regex-filter.

Thank you for your help!

We have tried a regex filter like:

```
<RegexFilter regex=".*db-thread.*" onMatch="ACCEPT" onMismatch="DENY"/>
```

The regulare expression seems not to take effect on the thread-name part of the line but only on the message part.

Answer (score 0):

There is no specialized filter for matching thread names. You have however two solutions:

- writing your own filter,
- using [`ScriptFilter`](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/filters.html#Script) and a scripting engine.

### Native filter

Writing a native script filter is easy:

```java
@Plugin(name = "ThreadNameFilter", category = Node.CATEGORY)
public final class ThreadNameFilter extends AbstractFilter {
    public static final class Builder extends AbstractFilter.AbstractFilterBuilder<Builder>
            implements org.apache.logging.log4j.core.util.Builder<ThreadNameFilter> {
        @PluginBuilderAttribute
        @Required
        private Pattern regex;

        @Override
        public ThreadNameFilter build() {
            return new ThreadNameFilter(getOnMatch(), getOnMismatch(), regex);
        }
    }

    @PluginBuilderFactory
    public static Builder newBuilder() {
        return new Builder();
    }

    private final Pattern regex;

    public ThreadNameFilter(final Result onMatch, final Result onMismatch, final Pattern regex) {
        super(onMatch, onMismatch);
        this.regex = regex;
    }

    @Override
    public Result filter(final LogEvent event) {
        return regex.matcher(event.getThreadName()).matches() ? getOnMatch() : getOnMismatch();
    }
}
```

Compile it with annotation processing enabled and you can use it like this:

```xml
<ThreadNameFilter onMatch="ACCEPT" onMismatch="DENY" regex="db-thread.*"/>
```

### Script filter

You can also use `ScriptFilter`. In order to do so you need to:

- if you are running Java 15 or higher, install a scripting engine, e.g. Nashorn:

  ```xml
  <dependency>
       <groupId>org.openjdk.nashorn</groupId>
       <artifactId>nashorn-core</artifactId>
       <version>15.4</version>
  </dependency>
  ```
- Add the selected script language to the whitelist, by adding it to the `log4j2.scriptEnableLanguages` variable. This can be done e.g. by adding:

  ```
  log4j2.scriptEnableLanguages = javascript
  ```

  to a `log4j2.component.properties` file in the classpath.

Once the scripting engine is installed and enabled, you can use `ScriptFilter` like this:

```xml
<ScriptFilter onMatch="ACCEPT" onMismatch="DENY">
    <Script language="javascript">logEvent.getThreadName().matches("db-thread.*");</Script>
</ScriptFilter>
```

**Remark:** if you want to use these filters as **global** filters (i.e. as direct children of `<Configuration>`), some adjustments are required.